# Remote Differential Compression with Diff Tools like Beyond Compare

Tags: beyondcompare4

Should I turn off Remote Differential Compression (RDC) on Windows 11 when using diff tools like Beyond Compare to sync files beteeen two computers?

Sync between Windows 10 computers is much faster than sync between Windows 10 and Windows 11 and I was wondering if this is related to RDC.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Compare doesn't do anything to specifically take advantage of Remote Differential Compression (RDC).

Scooter Software hasn't tested copy performance with RDC on vs RDC off, for internal testing we generally use default settings for each version of Windows.